# How can I get this background style similar to this site https://www.hackthebox.eu. background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

First check this site https://www.hackthebox.eu/. I just want to know how can I get background style similar to this site https://www.hackthebox.eu/ (molecular like structure).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If any answer here has helped you, please consider 'accepting' it; This will mark your question as solved, and also reward both you and the answerer some reputation - [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hackthebox.eu are using a library called "particles.js" to create the background

You can read up on how to use it here - 
https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/

Vincent's website has a play area where you can change the parameters to see what you like - https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/

If you want something identical to their site, you can use their config - https://www.hackthebox.eu/js/particlesjs-config.json

Note that this can sometimes get blocked by ad blockers and will not load. I would recommend renaming the js file to something different and it should get around the issue

Answer (score -1):

As a general recommendation, you can always inspect the source of the site and get to know how they are built pretty easily. Here, you can see that there's a div with the id `particles-js`, which implies on the library they've used. And diving a bit deeper, you can see there is a canvas inside that the library draws on.